# Hiding block title when customizing

Tags: 7, theming, blocks, hooks

I would like to hide the block title when customizing a block, but I didn't find any solution on the internet, Can you please help me?

```
function custom_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

  $hooks['user_login_block'] = array(
    'template' => 'templates/user_login',
    'render element' => 'form',
    // other theme registration code...
  );
  return $hooks;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it easily directly in the configuration page of block by adding `<none>` in the title field setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can also hide it by setting the CSS "display" property to "none."