# How to hide Quick Tabs Title

Tags: blocks

I don't find a way to hide the quick tab title. Is there a hard way if not straight forward? Because I just cant use the title which doesn't make sense in my context/content.

[image]

My quick tab title is "Property Tabs". There are 3 tabs under it. Below SS is showing only one tab because I have checked "Hide empty tabs". My tabs are all **blocks**

1. 3D Gallery
2. Image Gallery
3. Video Gallery

I don't want to show the "Property Tabs" (highlighted in SS). I have tried to give title as "" but its still showing the title literally "". Its not accepting "empty string" or "space"

Comment: why you try to hide them with css ?  set display:none ?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific - by hide, did you mean CSS display? Or removing it from HTML structure altogether? Or what Volker posted in [his answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/100452/16495)?

Comment: @molot I have updated the post. I am very new to drupal. Sorry for not being very specific

Comment: @Dudepal your quicktabs are in block? And it is a block's title? [See this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/16106/16495).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Quick Tabs settings (admin/structure/quicktabs/manage/...) there's a checkbox to hide the title of your content and use the custom Tab-Title instead.

[image]

If you want to hide the block title (of the quicktabs block) itself, you can insert `<none>` in the block settings...

[image]

Comment: my tab types are blocks and I guess that option simply hide the title of that particular block/node/view but not the title of the tab bar itself. Sorry if I was not clear

Comment: i updated my answer...